# Apache2/Tomcat: Redirecting root url

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have just moved my apache2/Tomcat9 server from windows to ubuntu.
ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are working fine. Known tomcat webapp urls are all passing through.

However, when I just enter the www.myservername.com it goes to the default var/www directory.

I tried redirecting using `000-default.conf`. The following works for `http://www.myservername.com` but does not work for `https://www.myservername.com`

ServerName www.myservername.com

```
ServerName www.myservername.com
<VirtualHost *:*>

    ServerName www.myservername.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://www.myservername.com/ddd-college-website/entry
</VirtualHost>
```

So, in short, typing `https://www.myservername.com/` into the browser, should take users to `https://www.myservername.com/ddd-college-website/entry`. But it's not happening

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: If you manually enter `https://www.myservername.com/ddd-college-website/entry` in browser address bar, does the page open?

Comment: yes, it opens. It is just the redirect from https://www.myservername.com that doesn't (temp fix was javascript redirect from index.html)

Comment: Is there another separate VirtualHost for https site?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It is a virgin Ubuntu 16 Apache2 server. I didn't see anything